# Wish a bit help with conditionals and operators

Tags: conditionals, search

Im trying to show results after search so that if there is under 10, it shows A, but if there is more than 10 results, it shows B. But I dont understand how to make this happen.

I tried this but it wont work:
`{if count == '1'}<h4>total results: <span>{absolute_results}</span>.</h4>{if:elseif count > '10'}<h4>There is more than 10 results. Refine your search?</h4>{/if}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it. `{count}` is the current count of the displayed entry in the tag's loop. Think of your entries as a numbered list, the `{count}` is the position in the list.

`{absolute_results}` however is [total number of entries in the "list"](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#absolute-results), so you want to build your conditional from it.

Here is one example using your markup:

```
{if count == 1}
    <h4>
        {if absolute_results > 10}
            There are more than ten results. Refine your search?
        {if:else}
            Total results: <span>{absolute_results}</span>
        {/if}
    </h4>
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you. I wrapped that inside if count == 1 (to show it only on top of the page, and not above all listed entries) and now it works like a charm.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer to reflect that context.